# Read-line from socket-stream in lisp

Tags: sockets, tcp, lisp, common-lisp, usocket

I am working on a TCP client in lisp, and am having difficulties reading/printing the socket-stream correctly.  When the client sends data to the server it should receive a response, and I need to write this to stdout.  This works correctly, except I am having an issue where the response is printing twice.  If I have multiple commands being sent, only the last one will be printed twice.  Here is my code:

```
(defun socket-print (string socket)
    (write-line string (usocket:socket-stream socket))
    (force-output (usocket:socket-stream socket)))


(defun socket-read (socket)
    (write-line (read-line (usocket:socket-stream socket) nil)))


(defun mytest (command)
    (let ((socket (usocket:socket-connect _IP_ _PORT_)))
        (socket-print command socket)
        (socket-read socket)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's printing twice.  I think it's *printing* (via **write-line**) once, and then **write-line** is *returning* the line, and the *REPL* is printing the return value.  E.g., if you modify your **mytest** to return **nil**, I think you'll see the output that you're expecting:

```
(defun mytest (command)
    (let ((socket (usocket:socket-connect _IP_ _PORT_)))
        (socket-print command socket)
        (socket-read socket)
        nil))
```

This should *print* the line with **write-line**, and then return **nil**, and the REPL will print **nil**.  Compare this with:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defun echo (line)
           (write-line line))
ECHO
CL-USER> (echo "hello")
hello
"hello"
CL-USER> (progn
           (echo "hello")
           (echo "world"))
hello
world
"world"
CL-USER> (progn
           (echo "hello")
           (echo "world")
           nil)
hello
world
NIL
CL-USER> (progn
           (echo "hello")
           (echo "world")
           (values))
hello
world
; No value
```

Also see:

- [How can I avoid the nil printed in the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17429729/1281433)
- [prevent terminal output in LISP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16369474/1281433)
- [When you type "hello, world" in Clojure REPL, why does it say 'nil'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1416067/1281433) (not Common Lisp, but same concept)